# Really Bad Performance While Gaming on Orgin Through Lutris (Pop os)

Tags: wine, games

I just recently switched from Windows to Linux (Pop OS), and I have been in the process of downloading my game library on Linux. However, a big problem I have had has been with Orgin. I got it running through Lutris, however, the one game I own there, Need For Speed Heat, has issues running, and I have no clue why. I don't know if this is the game, or Orgin itself, as I have no other game on Orgin to compare with. Also, the game ran perfectly at max settings on Windows 11, so it should at least be able to run not like a picture show on Linux I would assume. I looked for answers for awhile, but could not find anything that worked. Also, my PC is a lot quieter while running Need For Speed than it was on Windows, so clearly it is not using it's full power either.

Here is what I have tried: Running through newest Proton GE. Using Orgin through Steam instead of Lutris. Playing a few races to let the cache render. Lowering my Graphics Settings Incredibly Low. Trying some Steam launch commands (however didn't work because it has to go through Orgin first). Reinstalling Wine.

It could be a combination of things I have not tried, but those were the things I could figure out to try from basic google research.

Here are my specs too: RTX 2060 Intel Core i3 12100f 16gb DDR4 RAM

I appreciate the help in advance!
(Also, I don't know if I made it clear enough, but I am trying to fix performance issues with Need for Speed Heat as it is performing severely badly considering the specs of my PC. I don't know for sure, but I suspect it has something to do with my PC not utilizing much of the GPU and CPU during gameplay, as my PC is weirdly silent. However, this only happens on Orgin.)

Comment: I've never played NFSH, but according to [protondb](https://www.protondb.com/app/1222680) performance issues are fairly common with it.  e.g. one of the comments there says that after every EA app update, they have to start the game with proton 7.0-4, then quit, and restart it with proton experimental.  Maybe try that, or some of the other ideas there.   Also worth noting, you can **export** proton setting variables from the shell *before* running lutris/steam/EA/whatever, and they will be inherited by all child processes you run in that shell.

Comment: see also https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/issues/3955

Comment: I have now tried switching to proton 7.0-4, and then switching to the newest wine release on ProtonUp-QT. I also followed some of the Github advice that I could use, such and creating the user config file, and giving read only permissions to orgin. Which unfortunately, did not fix the problem. However, while still stuttering a lot, those modifications did make the game run just a little bit smoother, almost to the point of "kind of playable." I don't know what else I can do though, to make it reach at least a stable 30fps.

Comment: Some games just run badly on wine or proton. And Origin sucks badly (same for most other launchers/shopfronts - I just flat out refuse to buy games that require another account, another launcher any more. They just cause too many problems to be worth the bother.  If i buy a game on steam, i don't need and absolutely do not want another account on another service or some stupid social club or other spyware service or extra DRM.  I don't play multi-player games, so this boycott isn't difficult to stick to).

Comment: Yeah I get that, but since I already spent the money on the game, I am hoping there is a way I can maybe just play it, hence why I will keep this thread open in hopes for suggestions that at least improve performance a little bit, because, I can't simply get my money back.